# Renaming git branch name in pipeline yml file

Tags: yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

My git release branch is -  `release/release-0.0.1`

In bitbucket pipeline yml I can get the branch name with `${BITBUCKET_BRANCH}` which take the `release/release-0.0.1`

I want to get just the `release-0.0.1` portion.

How can I remove the `release/` ?

Comment: Used this,

TAG="$(echo ${BITBUCKET_BRANCH} | cut -d '/' -f 2)"

Answer (score 1):

you can use a shell command to remove the first part:

```
export BRANCH_NAME=$(echo $BITBUCKET_BRANCH | sed "s/[^\/]*\///")
```

This removes all characters before (and including) the first slash.